# Incomming Bubble Image showing with balnk Space how to delete?

Tags: ios, swift, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image]

In my JSQMessagesViewController, when I load incomming message bubbles, So In that blue bubbles beginning getting space how can remove that space whether anything need to disable??

Comment: It's depend on how you set your custom cell UI and constraints

Comment: I have referred the following URL no need to custom UI https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line will remove the blank space from beside the bubbles:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
```

Answer (score 1):

This White space is for Avatar container If you want to delet this I think you can try to modify in JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib and JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing.xib files by deleteing the Avatar container View and move the Bubble container to right.

**Before :**

[image]

**After :**

[image]

**You can Find those files at**
[image]